# Error: Could not find or load main class After creating jar for multi-module project

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I am using IntelliJ and gradle to create a multi-module spring project as shown below.
With the following build.gradle in the root folder, I have the following settings below. When invoked gradle build, a jar gets created in build/libs, however executing that jar I get the error message: 
**Error: Could not find or load main class com.connect.configuration.ConnectApplication
** When running the application without building via: gradle bootRun -- the application loads up correctly. However, executing the jar file after building the project, produces the error and the jar prints out the following: using

```
jar -tf myJar.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

[image]

```
plugins {
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

subprojects {
    group = 'com.connect.connect'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.9
    targetCompatibility = 1.9

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'java-library'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'
    }
    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.9.RELEASE")
        }
    }
}
```

**settings.gradle**

```
include 'connect-common'
include 'connect-ui'
include 'connect-services'
include 'connect-application'
include 'connect-configuration'
```

Comment: Check MANIFEST whether it indicates the main class or not.

Comment: In eclipse - 
1.run as run configurations and select main class, 
2. while exporting jar there are options to select main class, also to generate manifest file.
I hope similar setup will be there in eclipse,
Might be helpful for you.

Comment: Your applicaiton should apply the Spring Boot plugin to the project that create the jar (probably  `connect-application`).

Comment: @M.Deinum. this one ? apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'